# What does JPA @UniqueConstraint do in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate, why should I use the JPA tag:

```
@Table(name="tbl_sky",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"month", "day"})}
)
```

I know *when* to use it. It's used when the combination of fields (tuple) of a database table is unique. It's not used when there is a composite primary key because composite primary keys are always unique. Anyway, the database already enforces this "unique constraint" relationship, so what's the point of including this tag on my Hibernate annotations? How does using this tag help Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

It helps hibernate in schema generation (DDL) for your mappings. Look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html

Comment: I saw that earlier. It still doesn't answer the why. Now the question becomes "why does it matter if the DDL takes the UniqueConstraint into account, since the DB already does?" Thanks for the response.

Comment: It matters because you may want to generate your whole database schema from your mappings, including naming. For example: 
`@Entity
    @Table(
        name="EMPLOYEE", 
        uniqueConstraints=
            @UniqueConstraint(name="MY_UNIQUE", columnNames={"EMP_ID", "EMP_NAME"})
    )`
It would generate something like 'ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_UNIQUE UNIQUE(EMP_ID, EMP_NAME)'.